# что такое неделимая операция семафора?

Tags: c++

"Неделимая операция - это операция, которая не может быть прервана."  Непонятно это объяснение. Могли бы вы осветить более развернуто этот момент и если возможно с примером кода.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Два параллельных потока выполнения представляете? Нет никаких гарантий, кто что и когда делает. Вплоть до того, что вы выполняете присваивание типа

```
long long x = f(y);
```

где `long long` - 8 байт, а запись при этом идет по 4 байта - пишется одно слово, затем второе. Так вот, параллельное выполнение не гарантирует не только что никто не вклинится между вычислением функции и присвоением результата, но что даже такое сохранение будет выполнено без вмешательства другого потока. И если есть

```
Поток 1                     Поток 2
x = 0xFFFF0000;             x = 0xABCD1234;
```

то в результате может оказаться, что `x` не равно ни первому значению, ни второму, а, скажем, `x == 0xFFFF1234`. Специально привел пример понеприятнее.

А неделимая операция - во время выполнения которой переключение между потоками гарантированно не произойдет.

Так более-менее понятно?

Семафор - есть такой `std::mutex`, и если вы выполнили для него `lock()`, то пока не будет выполнен `unlock()`, все прочие операции `lock()` заставляют поток ожидать.

```
std::mutex m;

Поток 1                     Поток 2
m.lock();                   m.lock(); 
x = 0xFFFF0000;             x = 0xABCD1234;
m.unlock();                 m.unlock();
```

Тут вы гарантируете, что как бы причудливо не переплетались эти потоки, но `x` не примет какого-то непонятного значения, а будет либо `0xFFFF0000`, если первым захватил мьютекс второй поток, либо `0xABCD1234` - если первый. Т.е., например, первый поток пришел первым, вызвал `lock()`. Пришел второй поток, вызвал `lock()` - и остановился в ожидании, пока мьютекс не будет освобожден. Первый поток выполнил присваивание, вызвал `unlock()` и пошел дальше. И только теперь вызов `lock()` вторым потоком завершится, и он сможет выполнять свое присваивание.

Примерно так...

Comment: (D-side, сказал, что  этот коммент к его ответу Вы автоматом не увидите) вот habrahabr.ru/users/khizmax/topics/page2 неплохой цикл статей примерно на эту тему (если бы речь там не шла о lock-free то я бы сказал background)

Answer (score 2):

На практике я чаще встречаю *синоним*: **атомарная** операция (прямой перевод). Это операция, которая для "сторонних наблюдателей" (других потоков?) гарантированно **не может быть "в процессе"**: она либо уже *выполнилась*, либо ещё *не началась*.

*Неделимая*, потому что для наблюдателей снаружи она не может быть разделена на отдельные наблюдаемые шаги.

Эти операции важны, когда к некоторому элементу данных обращаются несколько потребителей **без синхронизации** (никто не говорит им, когда смотреть можно, а когда нет), и каждый потребитель должен видеть этот элемент данных в **целостном состоянии**.

Как семафор должен быть в состояниях **закрыт**/**открыт**.

Comment: @Harry, (D-side, Вы же этот коммент автоматом увидите) вот https://habrahabr.ru/users/khizmax/topics/page2/ неплохой цикл статей примерно на эту тему (если бы речь там не шла о lock-free то я бы сказал background)

Comment: @avp Harry не может получить уведомление от комментария под *моим* ответом, насколько я понимаю систему. Ссылка полезная! Предложите Harry добавить её в ответ, чтобы её увидело больше людей.

Comment: Спасибо. Я не слишком хорошо разбираюсь в таких тонкостях этого софта. Продублирую.